# Oracle PL/SQL how to join first letter of value in a row and another row

Tags: sql, oracle, join

First time asking question, I hope I didn't go wrong with title.

I have table with first and last name of the users. I need to fill the USER row in a way that:

- user must be written in a form of first letter of his first name and then with his full last name (all in lower case)
   Ivan Horvat = ihorvat
- I need to replace symbols č = c, ć = c, š = s
- if USER is repeated, there must be added a number of repetition (*1 not included*)

ihorvat, ihorvat2

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | user | first  | last   |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      | Ivan   | Horvat | 
|  2 |      | Matija | Horvat | 
|  3 |      | Ivan   | Babić  | 
|  4 |      |Tomislav| Jurišić| 
|  5 |      | Ivan   | Horvat | 
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

I know functions I can use functions LOWER, REPLACE, SUBSTR etc. but I don't know how to combine all this in one code.

Comment: From my point of view you should divide into 3 points you have mentioned. First being concatenation, second being replacement and third finding duplicated users. does you user column accept non-unique values?

Comment: @zagvir can you show us some basic code, please? right now, you are asking us to help you with your homework...

Comment: I can devide it into 3 points.

First being CONCAT(SUBSTR(first, 1, 1), last)
Second being REPLACE(REPLACE(user, č, ć)),š, s)...

I don't know how to do the last point and how to combine it all together in single procedure/function. I just started learning PL/SQL, I understand functions but i don't know how to combine them. In which module and how.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

- lines #1 - 7 - sample data
- `tuser` CTE (lines #8 - 15) creates desired format ("ihorvat" out of "Ivan Horvat") and translates characters
- the final `select` uses analytic function which creates "row numbers" for each `val`; `case` is used to concatenate that *row number* if it is larger than 1

---

```
SQL> with test (id, first, last) as
  2    (select 1, 'Ivan'    , 'Horvat'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Matija'  , 'Horvat'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Ivan'    , 'Babić'   from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Tomislav', 'Jurišić' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Ivan'    , 'Horvat'  from dual
  7    ),
  8  tuser as
  9    (select id,
 10       translate(lower(substr(first, 1, 1) || last),
 11                       'ĐŠŽĆČđšžćč',
 12                       'DSZCCdszcc'
 13                ) val
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  select id,
 17    val || case when row_number() over (partition by val order by id) = 1 then null
 18                else row_number() over (partition by val order by id)
 19           end as result
 20  from tuser
 21  order by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 ihorvat
         2 mhorvat
         3 ibabic
         4 tjurisic
         5 ihorvat2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution, but be aware that it is not optimal and it will perform bad on large tables!

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_users IS SELECT id, TRANSLATE(LOWER(SUBSTR(first,1,1) || last), 'ćčđšž', 'ccdsz') name FROM users;
    TYPE ty_users IS TABLE OF c_users%rowtype;
    t_users ty_users;

    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_users;
    FETCH c_users BULK COLLECT INTO t_users;
    CLOSE c_users;

    FOR i IN t_users.FIRST..t_users.LAST LOOP
        IF t_users.EXISTS(i) THEN
            v_count := 0;
            FOR j IN 1..i LOOP
                IF t_users.EXISTS(i) AND t_users(i).name = t_users(j).name  AND i <> j THEN
                    v_count := v_count + 1; 
                END IF;
            END LOOP;

            IF v_count > 0 THEN
                t_users(i).name := t_users(i).name || v_count;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF t_users.COUNT > 0 THEN 
        FORALL indx IN INDICES OF t_users
            UPDATE users SET username = t_users(indx).name WHERE id = t_users(indx).id;            
    END IF;
END;
```